# Set UIImageView height dynamically inside UITableViewCell according to cell height

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiimageview, constraints, cell

I have a problem with an UITableViewCell that has UIImageView and a UILabel. All constraints are set programmatically, so that the constraints are adjusted so that the height of the cell varies dynamically with the height of the UILabel plus a certain padding, while the UIImageView must adapt to the height of the UITableViewCell. However, when I place the image, the height of the cell increases until it is that of the Image.

```
    contentView.addSubview(coverView)
    contentView.addSubview(indexUnitLabel)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        coverView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
        coverView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
        coverView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
        coverView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 68),

        titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: padding),
        titleLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -padding),
        titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: coverView.trailingAnchor, constant: padding),
        titleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -padding)
    ])
```

Is there any way to set the constraints so that the height of the UIImageView adapts to the height of the cell dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you re-typed your code (instead of pasting the actual code), since you have coverView.**bottomAnchor** equal to contentView.**leadingAnchor**, as well as adding `indexUnitLabel` as a subview but then trying to constrain `titleLabel`...

So, your constraints should look like this:

```
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        coverView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
        coverView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
        coverView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor),
        coverView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 68),

        indexUnitLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: padding),
        indexUnitLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -padding),
        indexUnitLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: coverView.trailingAnchor, constant: padding),
        indexUnitLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -padding)
    ])
```

***BUT...*** that doesn't give auto-layout enough information about what you want done with the height of the cell.

You say you want the **label height** (plus padding) to determine the height of the cell, so add this line:

```
indexUnitLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)
```

That tells auto-layout to ***not*** expand the height of the label beyond its content.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving constraints to your `coverView` from `contentView`, give it from `coverView` to `titleLabel` . Adjust the padding accordingly. Also set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to false.

```
  titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
  coverView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

  titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: padding),
  titleLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -padding),
  titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: coverView.trailingAnchor, constant: padding),
  titleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -padding)

  coverView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLabel.topAnchor, constant: padding),
  coverView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: -padding),
  coverView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: padding),
  coverView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: -padding)
```

Comment: Didn't work. On set image, UIImageView height increases and so does UILabel height.